# Javascript HTML collection showing as 0 length

Tags: javascript

```
  var eval_table = document.getElementsByClassName("evaluation_table");
  console.log(eval_table);
```

This displays as:

```
[item: function, namedItem: function]0: 
    table.widefat.fixed.evaluation_table
    length: 1
    __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

However, when I try to get a length of `eval_table`, `eval_table.length`, it returns a value of `0`. I've used this approach before, had no issues with this approach before. Is there anything wrong with what I'm trying to achieve above?

Comment: [Works fine](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/7hc3qrhu/). Perhapes, a typo in your code?

Comment: Nope, no typo, perhaps my environment, working in wordpress, although this shouldn't affect vanilla javascript? @alexP

Comment: maybe your js is executed before the elements are created?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Are the elements already in the DOM when you're calling the function?

Comment: yeah, @alexP, if I console.log the collection itself it can see that they're there, it sees the length of them (seen in the above code snippet), however when I try to directly reference the length of these, returns 0.

Comment: See this example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7hc3qrhu/3/ - the code has been moved to `head`, so it executes before the elements are in the DOM (logs an empty array and `0` for length), but once you expand the collection in console the elements show up, because it shows the state of the object at the moment of expasion, and it is a live collection.

Comment: it's working in jsbin with a simple table http://jsbin.com/rupobicibi/1/`  , can you post more code , HTML may be

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is because your JS is running before the elements are rendered to the DOM. I bet the script you have running is loaded before the `<body>` of your html. You have two options:

1. Add the self-executing `<script>` as the last thing in your `<body>` tag or;
2. Wrap your function so that it waits for the DOM to be loaded before executing. You can do this with either:

   - jQuery's `$(document).ready` or
   - if you're not running jQuery: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {// do stuff })`

Code sample below:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
      var eval_table = document.getElementsByClassName('evaluation_table');
      console.log(eval_table, eval_table.length);
    });
  </script>
  <body>
    <div class="evaluation_table"></div>
    <div class="evaluation_table"></div>
    <div class="evaluation_table"></div>
    <div class="evaluation_table"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day. I would have accepted this answer.

Comment: Well now I feel like a moron.  Tried so many different solutions and it turned out they would probably have all worked, and I just needed to wait for the document to be ready!  Doh!

Comment: @blankmaker Thanks for this answer. Can you please have a look, this one is related to above question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601380/html-collection-length-is-0-even-after-dom-has-been-rendered

Comment: @blankmaker This still didn't help me, I'm still getting length 0 whereas a I can see 3 elements in it.

Comment: THANK YOU I've been searching for hours for this

Answer (score 4):

In order to access the element at position 0 of HTMLCollection you should use

```
        setTimeout(() => {
          let elms = document.getElementsByClassName('ClassName').item(0)
        }, 0);
```

Using `setTimeout` to make sure DOM is finished render.

Comment: This is an awful solution

Comment: Could be worse, though

Comment: at least it works

Answer (score 1):

You could write the code inside the

```
$('document').ready(function(){
         // your code
   });
```

or on body onload or on DOM ready

```
<body>
Your HTML here

<script>
// self executing function here
(function() {
    var eval_table = document.getElementsByClassName("evaluation_table");
    console.log(eval_table,eval_table.length);
})();
</script>
</body>
```

I have tried in this [jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7hc3qrhu/6/)