# Loop through elements that was added asynchronously

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, fetch, htmlcollection

I want to loop through Elements that was added asynchronously using fetch. Can somebody help? This is what I tried:

How I appended the Elements

```
    const body = document.querySelector("body");

    body.onload = function(){
        //loads the list of subjects
        getSubjects().then((data) => {
            let subjectSrting = ""; //initialize variable that holds the html of all the subjects semester wise

            // loops around each semester                
            data.forEach(function(semester){                    

                subjectSrting += "<div class='semester'> <div class='title yearTitle'>"+ semester.year +"</div> <div class='title semesterTitle'>"+ semester.semester +"</div>";

                // loops around each subject for each semester
                semester.subjects.forEach(function (subject){
                    let dis = ""
                    if(subject.type != "C"){
                        dis = "disabledSub";
                    }
                    subjectSrting += "<div class='subject "+dis+"'> <div class='sub'><span class='code'>" + subject.code + "</span><span class='name'>" + subject.name + "</span></div> <div class='subCredits'>" + subject.cred + "</div> <div class='attempt'> <input type='checkbox' id='" + subject.code + "' checked><label for='" + subject.code + "'>1st</label> </div> <button type='button' data_gpv='-1'  class='subResult'>SELECT</button> </div>";
                });                    

                subjectSrting += "</div>";

            });                

            let form = document.querySelector(".home form");
            form.innerHTML = subjectSrting;               

        })
    }
```

Here's where I find trouble to loop around the elements to get data-gpv values and to see if the checkboxes that were appended are checked or not:

```
    function calculateGpa(){
        let subjects = document.getElementsByClassName("home")[0].getElementsByClassName('subject');


        console.log(subjects.length); //logs 0, eventhough there are items in the HTMLCollection

        console.log(subjects); //logs a an HTMLCollection[] with the elements in it
        for(var i=0; i<subjects.length; i++){
            // get the gpv values and see if the chechbox is checked
            // cannot run this because subjects.length return 0
        }  
    }

    calculateGpa();
```

Comment: Subjects will be a collection of DOM nodes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and not an array. Try converting it to an Array using `const arr = [...subjects]`.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question
[HTMLCollection showing 0 length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211605/javascript-html-collection-showing-as-0-length)

Comment: @ben Tried it didn't work...

Comment: @asmaa it sounds similar, but it isn't. I need to find a way to loop around the HTMLCollection that I get...

Comment: Double-check your selector. If the length is zero then you are not retrieving the DOM elements correctly, or at the appropriate time.

Comment: @Ben when I console.log(subjects); It logs an HTMLCollections which contains all the elements that I need (to get the data from). but I am unable to access the data from the var subjects. Even subjects.item(0) returns null

Comment: This sounds like a race condition. Your call to `calculateGPA` must occur in a then, after the loading has completed, to ensure that you only try and perform the calculation after the asynchronous operation has completed.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are not waiting for the DOM to be populated with the result of the asynchronous call, before running the GPA calculation.

You can either, use the Promise API (`then`) to fix this, or you can supply a callback to `onLoad`.

```js
function onLoad() {
    getSubjects()
        .then((result) => {                 
            document.querySelector(".home").innerHTML = result              
        })
        .then(calculateGPA)
}

function getSubjects() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(`
        <div class="gpa">2.0</div>
        <div class="gpa">3.0</div>
    `), 3000))
}
    
function calculateGPA() {
    let total = 0
    const gpas = document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0].getElementsByClassName('gpa')

    console.log(gpas.length) // 2
    console.log(gpas) // HTMLCollection
    
    for(let g of [...gpas])
        total += Number(g.innerText)
        
    console.log(`The average gpa is: ${(total/gpas.length)}`) 
}


onLoad()
```

```html
<div class="home">
 Waiting for GPAs...
</div>
```