# reference a HTML tag with javascript that was generated from django json schema

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, jsonschema

I am trying to reference a HTML tag that is generated by a django's `django_jsonforms` [link](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonforms/) JSON Schema [link](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor#options) via javascript to dynamically update the form. For example 2 dropdowns in a form, if you make a selection in the 1st dropdown the 2nd dropdown should update. I've done this for HTML selection tags that I manually typed out but I am trying to get this to work for HTML generated by JSON Schemas. Here is what I've tried:

- inspect HTML page and try to call the tag by name with

`var project_selection = document.getElementsByName("form[project]")[0];`

this didn't work, which I was a little surprised by since I see when I inspect the page that the `select` tag has `name="form[project]"`

- then I thought maybe the JSON Schema renders the tag after the javascript runs so I tried adding `defer` into my `<script defer>` and that didn't work
- I tried using JSON Schema `$id` `#anchor` and `$ref` but none of those worked to reference the tag by ID

when I try a dummy  tag with name I get a NodeList back that I can access with project_section[0], however when I try to do the same thing for this select tag generated by django's json schema i get what it looks like an empty list but the tag is under it (however I cannot access it). See the figures below.

dummy test for h1 tag with name
[image]

actual django generated select tag with name (looks empty but it's not when I expand it, however, I cannot index [0] item on it)
[image]

I am sure someone has come across this before so I hope this is an easy answer.

At the end of the day, I know I need to use the following with the JSON Schema to do a similar to `onchange` as shown in [link](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor#listen-for-changes)

```
var element = document.getElementById('editor_holder');

var editor = new JSONEditor(element, options);

editor.on('change',function() {
  // Do something
});
```

thanks for taking a look in advance!

references:

- [json schema](https://json-schema.org/)
- [json schema editor github](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor)
- [json schema python](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [json schema python for django](https://github.com/Aristotle-Metadata-Enterprises/django-jsonforms)

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what was causing the issue. The DOM was not finished rendering the JSON Schema Form before the script was executing to call

`var project_selection = document.getElementsByName("form[project]");`

therefore wrapping the above script in a jquery ready function fixed the issue.

```
<script>
     $('document').ready(function(){
          var project_selection = document.getElementsByName("form[project]");
          console.log(project_selection);
          console.log(project_selection[0]);
     });
</script>
```

see more at: [Javascript HTML collection showing as 0 length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211605/javascript-html-collection-showing-as-0-length)

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure on this one, but you are using
`getElementsByClassName`, which is relevant to the *class name* of the element.  Not the name.  So for example:

```html
<div class="cname"></div>
```

That is a class name, form elements have a `name` attribute that you can query via
`var project_selection = document.getElementsByName("form[project]");`

Comment: hey thanks for the reply yes you are correct this select tag has `name=` but i tried getElementsByName("form[project]") and that didnt work either :(

Comment: i added more figures to the question showing more of the issue if that helps